# Restrict access to Sitecore Media assets from non-authenticated extranet users

Tags: customization, sitecore

I want a request to a media asset to behave like a request to a page/item. That is, if the user is not logged in they are bounced back to the login page with a referral back to the item they originally requested.

I can restrict access to a media asset by removing read access for extranet/anonymous user. This works but the user is sent to the "noaccess" page (defined in config) and then back to login with the "noaccess" page as the referer. I wonder if there is way to get the media request to first check authentication rather than access level (maybe with a custom handler) or extend the way a "no access" request is handled?

Answer (score 4):

I checked the code of the `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler` class and it works as follows:

1. Sitecore tries to get the mediaItem and then checks the users AccessRights
2. If access rights are fine, it will process the item
3. If the user doesn't have enough AccessRights, Sitecore redirects to the Site's login page which is set in the `<site name="yoursite" loginPage="">` section. If this loginPage is not set, Sitecore redirects to the `<setting name="NoAccessUrl" />` setting in the web.config.

I assume you have the loginPage setting set to your login page.
If this isn't the desired behavior, you could create a custom handler for the MediaRequestHandler.

Se the part of the code from the MediaRequestHandler which handles the insufficient access rights:

```
using (SecurityDisabler securityDisabler = new SecurityDisabler())

                {
                    media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaRequest.MediaUri);
                }
                if (media != null)
                {
                    Assert.IsNotNull(Context.Site, "site");
                    if (Context.Site.LoginPage != string.Empty)
                    {
                        loginPage = Context.Site.LoginPage;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loginPage = Settings.NoAccessUrl;
                    }
                    itemNotFoundUrl = loginPage;
                }
                else
                {
                    itemNotFoundUrl = Settings.ItemNotFoundUrl;
                }
                if (!Settings.RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(itemNotFoundUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(itemNotFoundUrl);
                }
```

See [this blogpost](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/07/file-download-dialog-box-for-sitecore.html) on how to create a custom MediaHandler